# Phong Reflection Model Parameters

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 3d, formula, 3d-reconstruction

**Question:** Can anyone refer me the Phong reflection model parameters for a face image taken for web-cam?

**Details:**

I am doing 3D reconstruction of 2D images using 3D Morphable Model as in this paper [Vetter & Blanz, 2003](http://gravis.cs.unibas.ch/publications/pami03.pdf).

There is a cost function which needs to be optimized using Newton Method. I need to give initialization values for the Newton method.

The below equation is the phong reflection model of an image. The ambient, diffuse and the specualr components are shown.

[image]

[Phong Reflection Model wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model)

Phong Parameters: Ks, Kd, Ka, α, Lm, V

I am estimating the above parameters using Newton method. The image is of human face and the camera is web-cam.

**I gave the below values:** Ks = Kd = Ka = 0.6 α = 5 Lm = [0 1 1] V = [0 0 1]

Can anyone comment on the above values and what can be a good initialization values for the parameters??

Answer (score 2):

My boss had a Siggraph paper about that some times ago, and proposes an online tool that retrieves a particular skin BRDF fitting to a Blinn-Phong model, depending on the gender, skin type etc.. The tool is available at :
http://gvi.seas.harvard.edu/ext/facescanning/index.html

Alternatively, you could check Matusik's BRDF database fittings at:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/addy/research/ngan05_brdf_supplemental_doc.pdf
and choose one BRDF that "looks like" skin (they didn't measure skin since they used balls).